# Issue with concurrent (iterated) invocations of a function that calls Promise.all()

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

This example is a simplification, but hopefully demonstrates my problem.  I suspect I am missing something obvious re: closure here.

The issue is that results being returned from my aggregation function below include the *final* set of personParams i.e. those resulting from the final iteration of the forEach , not the set of personParams that the function was called with.

```
let promiseArray = [];  // top level array of promises

let globalParams = { date: "2018-05-20" };
let people = [
              {name: "Tom",
               location: "Philadelphia"},
              {name: "Bob",
               location: "Austin"},
              {name: "John",
               location: "Philadelphia"}
             ];

people.forEach( person => {

    // Create indivdiualized parameter set
    let personParams = globalParams;
    personParams.name = person.name;
    personParams.location = person.location;

    // Push promise to array
    promiseArray.push(assembleResults(personParams));

});

Promise.all(promiseArray).then( results => {
    console.log("Final Output:", results);  
})

// individual data aggregation function
function assembleResults(iterationParams) {

    let promise1 = Promise.resolve({data: "Type A data about " + iterationParams.name});
    let promise2 = Promise.resolve({data: "Type B data about " + iterationParams.name});
    let promise3 = Promise.resolve({data: "Type C data about " + iterationParams.name});

    return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, iterationParams])
}
```

Updated with executable Fiddle @ JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shaunhurley/9r5k6j0c/

My expectation is that each iteration of assembleResults() is going to return an array that looks like:

```
[{data: "Type A data about <person's name>"},
 {data: "Type B data about <person's name>"},
 {data: "Type C data about <person's name>"},
 {date: "2018-05-20", name: "<person's name>", location: "<location>"}]
```

Where each array will have name set to "Tom", "Bob" & "John" respectively.  The final output would be an array or arrays per below.

```
[{data: "Type A data about Tom"},
 {data: "Type B data about Tom"},
 {data: "Type C data about Tom"},
 {date: "2018-05-20", name: "Tom", location: "Philadelphia"}]

[{data: "Type A data about Bob"},
 {data: "Type B data about Bob"},
 {data: "Type C data about Bob"},
 {date: "2018-05-20", name: "Bob", location: "Austin"}]

[{data: "Type A data about John"},
 {data: "Type B data about John"},
 {data: "Type C data about John"},
 {date: "2018-05-20", name: "John", location: "Philadelphia"}]
```

The actual result is that, while the correct data sets are being returned, the parameter set included in each array is showing the last/final parameter set generated i.e. name == "John" and location == "Philadelphia"

```
[{data: "Type A data about Tom"},
 {data: "Type B data about Tom"},
 {data: "Type C data about Tom"},
 {date: "2018-05-20", name: "John", location: "Philadelphia"}]

[{data: "Type A data about Bob"},
 {data: "Type B data about Bob"},
 {data: "Type C data about Bob"},
 {date: "2018-05-20", name: "John", location: "Philadelphia"}]

[{data: "Type A data about John"},
 {data: "Type B data about John"},
 {data: "Type C data about John"},
 {date: "2018-05-20", name: "John", location: "Philadelphia"}]
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

Shaun

Comment: What happened to John?? And to your dates? You're inconsistent with quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've made it an executable example and linked to a Fiddle for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
people.forEach(person => {
  let personParams = globalParams;
  personParams.name = person.name;

  promiseArray.push(assembleResults(personParams));
});
```

In the above code block you called `person.name` where I can see each person is a **String**. So you are getting ***undefined*** instead of the person's name. I think it should be `personParams.name = person`.

And `getResultsA` `getResultsB` and `getResultsC` of `assembleResults()` function should not return any data unless you have some person called ***undefined***.

I guess it's a dummy code you have posted. Posting the real code would have helped me answering more precisely.

### Modification

Bellow code would do your job:

```
people.forEach((person) => {
  // Create indivdiualized parameter set
  const personParams = {
    date: globalParams.date,
    name: person.name,
    location: person.location
  }
  // Push promise to array
  promiseArray.push(assembleResults(personParams));
});
```

Explaining how did it work would take too long and I guess you already know why did it behave like that. Please **google** *'JavaScript object creation'*.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, you are correct in that this is a simplified example - the full code is hundreds of lines.  I've updated it as an executable example and included the link to a Fiddle - results from the fiddle show in the console.